# Sql (Not in )operator query getting ignored

Tags: sql

I am writing an SQL query to select each row except those which have mentioned city values.
But somehow it's not working and selects rows with these cities.

```
Select * from Emp
Where City not in ('Suart', 'Vapi');
```

Upcoming output

```
Name   City

Kris   Surat
Joy    vapi
Riva   Goa
Jeni   Mumbai 
Maya   Sayan
```

Expected output

```
Name   City
Riva   Goa
Jeni   Mumbai 
Maya   Sayan
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data, the expected result and the result you get - all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: You can also give us a SQL fiddle, e.g using https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: I would not worry if it selects every row. I would worry if the selected rows contain those cities.

Comment: Suart <> Surat, vapi <> Vapi (if case sensitive collation.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your data must be case sensitive or spaces added.
Try this if it works

```
    Select * from Emp
      Where lower(ltrim(rtrim(City))) not in ('suart', 'vapi');
```

Or

```
  Select * from Emp
      Where lower(ltrim(rtrim(City))) not like '%suart%' OR
       lower(ltrim(rtrim(City))) not like '%vapi%'
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: This is mostly standard to all dbs especially oracle

Comment: LTRIM and RTRIM aren't very standard. Besides not like OR not LIKE is mostly true. Use AND instead.